# configure script and ldid

Tags: ios, gcc, scripting, jailbreak

The excerpt form the configure scripts fails due to `Killed: 9`  error, which is that iOS 5 can only run **signed** apps.  So I need to find a way to put `ldid -s` some where in these tests, only problem is where.

Anyone???

fails with

```
checking build system compiler gcc... no
checking build system compiler gcc -g -O2 ... no
checking build system compiler cc... no
checking build system compiler gcc... no
checking build system compiler c89... no
checking build system compiler c99... no
configure: error: Cannot find a build system compiler
```

and config.log

```
onfigure:15586: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:15586: $? = 0
configure:15586: result: yes
configure:15586: checking sys/time.h presence
configure:15586: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:15586: $? = 0
configure:15586: result: yes
configure:15586: checking for sys/time.h
configure:15586: result: yes
configure:15677: checking build system compiler gcc
configure:15690: gcc conftest.c
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit'
configure:15693: $? = 0
./configure: line 15675: 27218 Killed: 9               ./a.out
./configure: line 15695: ./b.out: No such file or directory
./configure: line 15695: ./a.exe: No such file or directory
./configure: line 15695: ./a_out.exe: No such file or directory
./configure: line 15695: ./conftest: No such file or directory
configure:15700: result: no
configure:15677: checking build system compiler gcc -g -O2
configure:15690: gcc -g -O2  conftest.c
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit'
configure:15693: $? = 0
./configure: line 15675: 27234 Killed: 9               ./a.out
./configure: line 15695: ./b.out: No such file or directory
./configure: line 15695: ./a.exe: No such file or directory
./configure: line 15695: ./a_out.exe: No such file or directory
./configure: line 15695: ./conftest: No such file or directory
configure:15700: result: no
```

And finally the ./configure script..

```
if test -n "$CC_FOR_BUILD"; then
      { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking build system compiler $CC_FOR_BUILD" >&5
    $as_echo_n "checking build system compiler $CC_FOR_BUILD... " >&6; }
    # remove anything that might look like compiler output to our "||" expression
    rm -f conftest* a.out b.out a.exe a_out.exe
    cat >conftest.c <<EOF
    int
    main ()
    {
      exit(0);
    }
    EOF
    gmp_compile="$CC_FOR_BUILD conftest.c"
    cc_for_build_works=no
    if { { eval echo "\"\$as_me\":${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \"$gmp_compile\""; } >&5
      (eval $gmp_compile) 2>&5
      ac_status=$?
      $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
      test $ac_status = 0; }; then
      if (./a.out || ./b.out || ./a.exe || ./a_out.exe || ./conftest) >&5 2>&1; then
        cc_for_build_works=yes
      fi
    fi
    rm -f conftest* a.out b.out a.exe a_out.exe
    { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: $cc_for_build_works" >&5
    $as_echo "$cc_for_build_works" >&6; }
    if test "$cc_for_build_works" = yes; then
      :
    else
      as_fn_error $? "Specified CC_FOR_BUILD doesn't seem to work" "$LINENO" 5
    fi

    elif test -n "$HOST_CC"; then
      { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking build system compiler $HOST_CC" >&5
    $as_echo_n "checking build system compiler $HOST_CC... " >&6; }
    # remove anything that might look like compiler output to our "||" expression
    rm -f conftest* a.out b.out a.exe a_out.exe
    cat >conftest.c <<EOF
    int
    main ()
    {
      exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Also, it's a capital `-S` - the lowercase `s` *removes* the fake codesign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit that my ability to read anything but the simplest shell scripts is pretty poor, but basically, you need to fake codesign the executable before you run it.  It looks like the executable you want to run is called `conftest`, right?  So, try signing it in this block:

```
if { { eval echo "\"\$as_me\":${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \"$gmp_compile\""; } >&5
  (eval $gmp_compile) 2>&5
  ac_status=$?
  $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
  test $ac_status = 0; }; then

  #begin added code
  ldid -S ./conftest
  #end added code

  if (./a.out || ./b.out || ./a.exe || ./a_out.exe || ./conftest) >&5 2>&1; then
    cc_for_build_works=yes
  fi
fi
```

Obviously, you might need to supply the full path to `ldid` (e.g. `/usr/bin/ldid`) if it's not found in the existing `PATH`.

**Update:** per poster's comment below, `a.out` is actually the executable that needs to be signed, not `conftest`.

Comment: @JohnBruseliusJensen, can you give us some more information than that?  What are you seeing?  Console output?  Error messages?  "Still no good" isn't very useful.

Comment: Sorry, 5 minutes ago I found  'test $ac_status = 0; }; then ldid -S ./a.out' to be working but now I'm stuck once again..with configure: error: Cannot determine executable suffix

Comment: @JohnBruseliusJensen, ok, that helps.  It looks like this is no longer a problem with code signing.  It might be best then, to post a **new** question, with the updated code in your script, and give it a different title (since `ldid` isn't the problem anymore).  That way, you'll get help from people with the right expertise.  Good luck!